# Get configurations of apps used in GSuite

Tags: api, google-api, google-workspace

Is there a way to programmatically or using APIs to get the configurations of all the apps that are being currently used in G Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "configurations" (i.e if you are looking for permissions) you may be able to one of either (or a mix of both) [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)
 and [gsuite-oauth-third-party-app-report](https://github.com/slackhq/gsuite-oauth-third-party-app-report/wiki)